# nested for loops with variable used in the nested loop windows batch

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, for-loop, nested

I have a first loop and a second loop but the variable from the first loop always stays the same in the second loop. how do i get the actual value of the second loop?

```
REM @echo off
set fastestserver=none
set fastestresponse=99999999ms

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (fileservers.txt) do (
        for /F "skip=8 tokens=9 delims= " %%B in ('ping -n 3 %%A') do (
        echo %%A
        echo %%B
        set fastestresponse=%%B
        set actualpingserver=%%B
            if /I "%fastestresponse:~,-2%" GTR "%actualpingserver:~,-2%" (
            set fastestresponse=%%B
            set fastestserver=%%A
        )
    )
)

REM @echo on
echo %fastestserver%
echo %fastestresponse%
```

in the fileserver.txt there are some servers inside, each get pinged and i want to get the average ping, if the ping is smaller then of the one before it should replace the 2 variables (fastestserver , fastestresponse ).

Problem now is that if i debug the script it always takes for

```
if /I "%fastestresponse:~,-2%" LSS "%actualpingserver:~,-2%"
```

so somehow from the second for the fastestresponse does not get filld because the value is always 999999999ms.

Thanks already for a hint/helping answer

Comment: you need delayed expansion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
REM @echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set fastestserver=none
set fastestresponse=99999999ms

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (fileservers.txt) do (
        for /F "skip=8 tokens=9 delims= " %%B in ('ping -n 3 %%A') do (
        echo %%A
        echo %%B
        set actualpingserver=%%B

        if /I "!fastestresponse:~,-2!" GTR "!actualpingserver:~,-2!" (
            set fastestresponse=%%B
            set fastestserver=%%A
        )
    )
)

REM @echo on
echo %fastestserver%
echo %fastestresponse%

endlocal
```

more [info about delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)